# Django inside virtualenv keeps using wrong Python

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, virtualenv

I cannot, for the life of me, find a simple way to configure a (Linode Debian 6) server correctly with Django 1.8, Python 2.7.3, and virtualenv. Here's the steps I took:

```
 mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 curator
```

This creates a VirtualEnv for me under /srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator

Now I run:

```
pip install django
```

And Django 1.8 is successfully installed. Then, I switch to /srv/www/curator and run:

```
django-admin startproject cmscore
```

I then follow the [Django Apache mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) instructions and end up with an Apache conf file under my sites-available directory looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName cms.example.com
  ServerAlias cms.example.com cms.example2.com
  ServerAdmin errors@example.com

  DocumentRoot /srv/www/curator/public_html

  WSGIDaemonProcess cms.example.com python-path=/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator/bin/python:/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup cms.example.com
  WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/curator/cmscore/cmscore/wsgi.py

  <Directory /srv/www/curator/cmscore/cmscore>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </Files>
  </Directory>

  Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/curator/public_html/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/curator/public_html/favicon.ico
  Alias /css /srv/www/curator/public_html/css
  Alias /js /srv/www/curator/public_html/js
  Alias /img /srv/www/curator/public_html/img
  Alias /static/admin /srv/www/curator/public_html/admin
  Alias /static /srv/www/curator/public_html/static
  Alias /media /srv/www/curator/public_html/media

  ErrorLog /srv/www/curator/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /srv/www/curator/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The Django docs mention an `WSGIPythonPath` directive, but I get an error that `WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section` when I use this.

With this configuration I get a 500 error (well obviously, there's a lot of settings I haven't added yet for example) but not one that I would expect. I get this (IPs blanked by me):

```
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=21802): Target WSGI script '/srv/www/curator/cmscore/cmscore/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=21802): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/curator/cmscore/cmscore/wsgi.py'.
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/www/curator/cmscore/cmscore/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]      fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]                      ^
[Thu May 21 14:55:16 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, this appears to be an error which occurs when Django 1.8 is being using by an earlier version of Python than 2.7. To debug, I threw this into the top of my wsgi.py file:

```
import sys

activate_this = '/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/curator/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.stderr.write(sys.version)
```

And in my Apache error log, I see:

```
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:18:12)
```

I've tried every trick that I can think of (tricks that worked with existing virtualenvs of Django 1.6 and Python 2.7 on the exact same server!) including shebangs pointing to the correct Python install in my manage.py file, but I cannot find any way to get this to work.

I know I'm missing something really obvious here, but I am blind to it, can anyone help?

Comment: Which python version is the default? Which Python version is mod_wsgi compiled with?

Comment: 2.6.6 is what I get when I run `python` outside of a virtualenv, so that's the default. Ultimately I wish I could trash the whole server and start again but that's not really possible with a multitude of production sites already running on it (and plenty of overhead for more too).

Comment: I definitely understand the frustration. I suppose `mod_wsgi` is compiled with 2.6.6 then? `mod_wsgi` requires recompling to the Python version you want to use.

Comment: `/srv/www/curator/cmscore/cmscore/wsgi.py` -does it have execution permission?

Comment: @WTower That sounds likely, I guessed that because other Django projects seemed to be invoking 2.7, that it had worked before, but they're using Django 1.6, so perhaps they were 'just lucky'

Comment: @salmanwahed I believe so

Comment: Would you like me to post you how I recompile `mod_wsgi` on my boxes? They re ubuntu but that could be easily related to your Debian.

Comment: Will the recompilation affect existing Python2.6 Django setups? If not, then yeah I'd be interested in doing that